# Entity Framework 4 and MVC 3 - Inheritence and Loading Derived Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, entity-framework-4

I've got some common properties (CreatedBy, CreatedOn, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn) for nearly all of my entities.  I decided to have a BaseEntity with these properties and then have all of my other entities inherit from this one.

For example:

BaseEntity --> Question

BaseEntity --> Answer

Now how do I load questions from my model container?

There is no `db.Questions` or `db.Answers` any more.  Just `db.BaseEntities`.

Specifically I want to load all questions by their subject - so normally I would say `db.Questions.Where(q => q.Subject.Id.Equals(subjectId))`.

How do I do this now?

Many thanks,
Pete

Comment: You can still have the derived type `DbSet<T>` on your context, so you can still have `db.Questions` etc. Anyway you can use the `OfType<T>` to get a specific type: `db.BaseEntities.OfType<Question>().Where(q => q.Subject.Id.Equals(subjectId))`

Comment: @nemesv: Your comment is the answer and you could write it as such.

Comment: Yes code first.  Thank you nemesv OfType() is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are multiple types of inheritance mapping strategies that you can use to configure your database

- [Table per hierarchy (TPH)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) - this is used by default, so currently you get only one table in database
- [Table per type (TPT)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)
- [Table per concrete type (TPC)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)

You can also add sets of concrete types to your DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

And the most important  - I would prefere composition over inheritance in your place. This feels more natural

```
public class HistoryRecord
{
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

and use it as complex type inside Question, Answer, etc

```
public class Question
{
     public HistoryRecord HistoryRecord { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The default for me is TPTS (Table-Per-Type-Strategy) and I do get a table for each entity, albeit prefixed with BaseEntities_.  How do I get the other types - currently there is only 1 option (TPTS) in the dropdown on the model designer in VS2010.  I like the HistoryRecord idea though - that way I can hold a collection on each entity too.

Comment: I specifically asked about using code first. There is no dropdown and model designer for code first in visual studio :)

Comment: Erm yeah :)   - model first, sorry.  Either way I like the HistoryRecord idea so that I can have a collection of "changes" recorded and build a history trail.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a base class for this.

You'll end up with one entity set and have to use typeof(X).

Worst of all, this may break future inheritance of other entities, especially if some are table per type, some are table per hierarchy and some are mixtures of the two.

Instead, use partial classes to define a common interface with the aspect properties (CreatedBy, CreatedOn, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn).

Edit: The base entity will also require a table with the PKs of all your entities in it.
This will cause the table to be unnecessarily large and may result in performance hits during queries and inserts.

Comment: Are you saying I should repeat those 4 properties on every table, then create a partial class for each entity and have them implement, ISomeInterface?  I was kinda trying to get away from so much work when adding a new entity.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: Good point, thanks.  I've decided to go with archil's answer and have a collection of HistoryRecords linked to each entity - so that I can have a history trail.